# Ionic Push notification not working in IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

Hi I am developing ionic app for android and IOS but I am facing issue with push notification. My notification status as below

```
"data": [
    {
      "config": {
        "query": {
          "$and": [
            {
              "details.email": {
                "$regex": "prit"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "notification": {
          "title": "Test Push",
          "payload": {},
          "android": {
            "title": "Test Push",
            "priority": "high",
            "message": "Get 150% off!cxzczxcxzc"
          },
          "ios": {
            "title": "Test Push",
            "priority": 10,
            "message": "Get 150% off!cxzczxcxzc"
          },
          "message": "Get 150% off!cxzczxcxzc"
        },
        "profile": "dev"
      },
      "created": "2017-03-07T10:19:07.563387+00:00",
      "status": "locked",
      "uuid": "82a2a7be-b7ad-41c3-abca-d5243b040c76",
      "state": "enqueued",
      "app_id": "1e54f22e"
    },
],
  "meta": {
    "version": "2.0.0-beta.0",
    "status": 200,
    "request_id": "d70268c5-3875-4e78-cef6-a17927b04917"
  }
}
```

here state is in enqueued (`"status": "locked"`) and `"status": "locked"`,.

I am not understanding its meaning. due to this I am not able to receive the any push notification. Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: I am facing the same problem with ios in ionic.

Comment: I am facing same issue, any lead to proceed?

Comment: @KanakSony I have faced this issue in sending the push from postman. this issue is came bcoz of wrong API token or wrong push token. please check tokens are correct. for more info http://legacy.docs.ionic.io/docs/push-sending-push#section-notification-status

Comment: Hi @Pritish, thanks for responding. I have checked tokens are correct. We are trying to send notifications using Curl and Postman and both behave same. We are badly blocked in iOS notifications. When we try any online Push Notifications tool to send notification in a native app using same certificates - notifications are received perfectly. But, ionic 2 app does not seem to proceed. Although, it generates device token correctly.

Comment: Hello Pritish and @kanak-sony, do you have solved this issue? I'm having same problem :)

Comment: @KanakSony yes after re-creating aps push certificates and other prod certificate I am able to send the push on real device. may be this create a problem for you try this.  If you are using ionic.io to send the push then so create prod profile for push add respected .p12 files to the profile. Hope so this will help you. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Pritish I created different certificates and configuring same carefully did the trick. Thanks!
@Lito Please do as Pritish suggested.